# Use Ubuntu on a USB everytime

Tags: live-usb

I have to start using Ubuntu again. I don't have the right to dual boot my current laptop and I don't like virtual machines.
I saw a lot of post and tuto about booting ubuntu on a USB, but i saw that it is mostly for debugging an OS and your files are temporary.
My question:
Can I be using Ubuntu for work purposes on a USB every time?
Does a persistent bootable ubuntu allows me to save any files in Ubuntu?

Comment: First question, legacy boot or EFI ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a normal live installation you can't save files.

But if you create yourself a persistent ubuntu Installation you can. That's the point of a persistent ubuntu. It allows you to save files and therefore config files as well.

Your system might not be as fast as a dual boot or even in a virtual box, but if you don't have any other chance, it is still usable